# Is jQuery faster than css/xpath selectors for IE 8.0 in Selenium?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selenium, selenium-rc

I am planning to run my existing selenium tests in IE 8.0. After checking few blogs and reading [this](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/why-jquery-in-selenium-css-locators-is-the-way-to-go/), I tried to run my tests using jQuery locators using the method mentioned [here](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-use-jquery-to-create-custom.html). My tests uses a lot of index based selectors, like in `xapth=div[class='myclass][index]`. In jQuery I tried `.myclass:eq(index)` to retrieve the elements. But I found jQuery to be much slower than xpath in IE and FF for these operations. Is there a faster way in jQuery to select nth element?

I am using Selenium 1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jQuery documentation:

> Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead.